# Can someone upload a malicious file to ipfs that could damage my react app that renders it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ipfs

If I have a react app that is open source that renders other users ipfs files inside the app. Is it possible for a user to upload a malicious file to ipfs that could update a react hook with with their own code?

Comment: Without more context and example code this question is hard to answer. However, a general rule is that you should never trust user input. When handling uploaded files a RCE (remote code execution) might be possible